# OpenShift 3 : unable to clone a private BitBucket repository

Tags: openshift, bitbucket

I'm trying to migrate from OpenShift 2 to OpenShift 3.
I have created a new app on OpenShift 3 but I'm struggling to clone my BitBucket private git repository to it. (I had no problem with OpenShift 2).

I have tried setting secrets (SSH or Basic Authentication) in Build/Advanced Options but without luck.

Here is the error message :

```
Cloning "git@bitbucket.org:(myusername)/(myrepository).git" ... error:
build error: Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from
remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are using a private BitBucket repository? If yes, what steps did you take to register a repository SSH key in BitBucket, create the ``sshauth`` secret, allow the ``builder`` service account to access the secret, and then configure your build to use it for that repository?

Comment: It's a private repository yes.
I have set the BitBucket SSH key in source secret

Comment: As already asked, can you list what steps you did? Did you use ``ssh-keygen`` to create a new repository SSH key? Did you register the public part of the key as an access key on the private repository on BitBucket? Did you create a secret in OpenShift using ``oc secrets new-sshauth``? Did you allow the ``builder`` to use the secret by running ``oc secrets link``? How then did you edit the build configuration to use the source secret? Or did you try and set it all up through the web console? A bit more detail will help to understand what you may have missed.

Comment: FWIW. I am writing a blog post series on how to use private Git repositories with OpenShift. I have written posts for GitHub and GitLab, and will be doing that for BitBucket start of the new week. The posts should be available in next couple of weeks.

Comment: I set it all up through the web console. In "source configuration" I chose "create new secret", set authentication type to SSH  key, then browse to my SSH private key. I didn't checked "use a custom .gitconfig file". I have tried setting the same secret in "Build secret" but still get the same error

Comment: If you created the secret from secrets menu, did you select the option to link to a service account, and then select ``builder``. If you didn't, run the ``oc secrets link builder yoursecretname``.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't see this option when I create a secret. The only optino I see is a checkbox "use a custom .gitconfig file". However I tried to set the same key in "build secrets" part but still get the same error. I tried the oc command line with my secret name but still the same error message.

Comment: If you don't see the option then you likely aren't creating the secret from the secrets page, but doing it as part of the application creation by clicking on 'Create New Secret' below the 'Source Secret' selection drop down. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes exactly. However I tried in the secrets page but it's the same problem.

Comment: Does your SSH key pair have a passphrase? You cannot use a SSH key pair with a passphrase with OpenShift. Best practice is to create a separate SSH key pair just for OpenShift to access the private Git repository and register the public key with BitBucket against that repository only, and then use the private key in OpenShift.

Comment: I tried again without passphrase but still the same error

Comment: I switched to basic authentication, which works well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this your own OpenShift cluster? If yes, is it behind a firewall that may be blocking SSH connections? Also, which specific version of OpenShift 3 is it?

Answer (score 12):

The steps if working from the command line are as follows:

1) Create a new SSH key pair for use with the repository. This cannot have a passphrase.

```
ssh-keygen -C "openshift-source-builder/repo@bitbucket" -f repo-at-bitbucket -N ''
```

This will generate files:

```
repo-at-bitbucket
repo-at-bitbucket.pub
```

being the private and public key files.

2) Go to *Settings->Access keys* for the repository on BitBucket, select *Add key* and in the popup window enter the key name `openshift-source-builder` and paste in the contents of the public key file. In this case `repo-at-bitbucket.pub`. Confirm creation by clicking on *Add key* on the popup window.

3) Create a secret in OpenShift for the key by running:

```
oc secrets new-sshauth repo-at-bitbucket --ssh-privatekey=repo-at-bitbucket
```

4) Enable access to the secret from the `builder` service account.

```
oc secrets link builder repo-at-bitbucket
```

5) In order that OpenShift knows the secret is for this specific private Git repository and automatically uses it, annotate the secret with the SSH URI for the repository.

```
oc annotate secret/repo-at-bitbucket \
    'build.openshift.io/source-secret-match-uri-1=ssh://bitbucket.org/yourusername/private-repo.git'
```

Very important here is the form of the URI. In the BitBucket web interface it will show it as:

```
git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/private-repo.git
```

Do not use that. You need to use the SSH form of the URI here.

6) We can then deploy the application from the private Git repository.

```
oc new-app httpd~git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/private-repo.git --name mysite
```

Okay to use `git@bitbucket.org:yourusername/private-repo.git` here, or could also use the SSH form of the URI.

You can also do all this from the web console instead. Important if creating the secret as a separate step in web console to link the `builder` service account when doing that. If create the source secret when deploying, then it will automatically link the `builder` service account.

Note that if the OpenShift instance has a firewall between it and BitBucket and SSH connections are blocked, this will not work. In that case you need to fall back to using a personal access token (app password) over a SSH connection using HTTP basic authentication.

---

These details are now much better explained by the blog post series starting with:

- https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-1-best-practices/