# Make Openshift V3 connected with Github repo

Tags: github, openshift, credentials

I'm having a hard time getting OpenShift V3 connected with my Github repo. I tried to follow a tutorial on https://learn.openshift.com but they don't elaborate credentials issues between OpenShift and Github

Then, I tried to run the new app process through the CLI. No success either.

```
    >oc new-app https://github.com/<repo>
--> Found image da99a88 (4 weeks old) in image stream "openshift/nodejs" under tag "6" for "nodejs"

    Node.js 6
    ---------
    Node.js 6 available as docker container is a base platform for building and running various Node.js 6 applications and frameworks. Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run across distributed devices.

    Tags: builder, nodejs, nodejs6

    * The source repository appears to match: nodejs
    * A source build using source code from https://github.com/<repo> will be created
      * The resulting image will be pushed to image stream "appname:latest"
      * Use 'start-build' to trigger a new build
      * WARNING: this source repository may require credentials.
                 Create a secret with your git credentials and use 'set build-secret' to assign it to the build config.
    * This image will be deployed in deployment config "appname"
    * Port 8080/tcp will be load balanced by service "appname"
      * Other containers can access this service through the hostname "appname"
--> Creating resources ...
    imagestream "appname" created
    buildconfig "appname" created
    deploymentconfig "appname" created
    service "appname" created
--> Success
    Build scheduled, use 'oc logs -f bc/<repo>' to track its progress.
    Run 'oc status' to view your app.
```

When I look on the log it says that Openshift could not connest the repo on the Github side

```
Cloning "https://github.com/<repo>" ...
error: build error: failed to fetch requested repository "https://github.com/<repo>" with provided credentials
```

---

**Update:**
Following very helpful answers and comments by ***user2983542*** and ***Graham Dumpleton***, I created public and private `SSH keys` with the following [tutorial](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/). I created the key with a passphase, but I'm a bit confused with the following statement at [OpenShift blog](http://hhttps://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-1-best-practices/):

> One saving grace is that OpenShift will not allow you to use a key-pair where the private key has a passphrase. A best practice, which I am sure you are following, is that your primary identity SSH key should always have a passphrase; this will prevent you from inadvisedly using your primary identity SSH key.

Anyway, I'm trying to proceed with passphase… I deployed the public key on Github end. Afterwards, I created `secret` of type `kubernetes.io/ssh-auth` on OpenShift and linked it to the deployment as an environmental variable.

The Github section of BuildConfig looks as the following:

```
triggers:
    - github:
        secret: M6_whatever...
      type: GitHub
```

Deployment fails with the following message:

```
--> Scaling myappname-1 to 1
--> Waiting up to 10m0s for pods in rc myappname-1 to become ready
error: update acceptor rejected myappname-1: pods for rc "myappname-1" took longer than 600 seconds to become ready
```

Could you, please, point me, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create a source clone secret. Depending on what version of OpenShift you are running there may be different options available to you. SSH key authentication should be standard across all versions.

You should generate a new SSH key pair and upload your public key to Github. [See the docs at Github for instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/) You will just need to create a secret with your private key. Example:

`oc secrets new-sshauth sshsecret \
    --ssh-privatekey=$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa_examplekey`

You may then need to link this secret to the `builder` service account using `oc secrets link new-sshauth`

See the OpenShift docs [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#source-clone-secrets) for more info and options for 3.6 but refer to your own version as required

Finally you will need to update the BuildConfig object to reference the new secret. `oc set build-secret --source bc/example-build sshsecret`

Comment: You should not use your primary identity SSH key (id_rsa), as you likely use that for other things like accessing hosts over SSH. In that situation it is a very bad idea to be uploading your private key to a separate system. A primary identity key usually also has a passphrase on it and OpenShift cannot use a key pair with a passphrase on it. So create a separate key pair just for use by OpenShift and register the public key as a deploy key against the repository in GitHub.

Comment: There will be a new series of blog posts coming out soon on blog.openshift.com about use of private Git repositories with OpenShift and various best practices you should use.

Comment: It is also not clear whether OP has edited the build configuration to use the source secret. That is, run ``oc set build-secret --source``, or edited the build configuration resource definition by hand.

Comment: You can see steps required for Bitbucket at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45910867/128141 but GitHub is similar.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, the entire community of OpenShift users will apperciate if OpenShift could provide _step-by-step really tested & worked_ documentation how to connect the private Git rep to the OpenShift platform.

Comment: @MikeB. There is a series of six blog posts about to come out on the topic of using private Git repositories.

Comment: Also note - you'll have to create a separate SSH key for each private git repo you setup (GitHub requires this).

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton thank you for your response and comments. I added an update to my initial question.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton, thank you for the blog post. Could you, please, have a look on the updated question, there is still issue with the connection to the private Githun repository. Thanks.

Comment: @igorM what is the output of 'oc get events'

Comment: @MikeB. What shows in the build logs, that is the more important one if you believe this still relates to pulling down source code.

Comment: And you cannot have a passphrase on the SSH key pair. You suggest you are, but as explained in blog, in text and in examples, when creating the key pair which you use with OpenShift you should not use a passphrase. Best practice around passphrase is for your primary identity key. You should not though use your primary identity key with OpenShift, nor start using the key you generated for OpenShift as your primary identity key.

Comment: The GitHub instructions are bad in the sense they they tell you to generate the key pair as your primary identity key. Don't do that. Use the command from the blog post.

Comment: @user2983542     C:\>oc get events
No resources found.

Comment: Dear @GrahamDumpleton, thank you for the blog posts, especially for the parts `2A` and `2B`, it helped us to solve an issue. One minor idea: in the the command line sample `oc secrets new-sshauth repo-at-github --ssh-privatekey=repo-at-github` to write `%name_of_secret%` and `%path_to_private_key%` instead of general `repo-at-github`. It will help to understand the meaning of the command's argument.

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this and still cannot figure it out. One key thing is that you have set up your git URL using SSH and not HTTPS. I initially did this and it failed in the same way as mentioned in the question: `oc new-app https://github.com/mygit/my-repo.git --name=myapp`. It worked when I created the app like this instead: `oc new-app openshift/php~git@github.com:mygit/my-repo.git --name=myapp`.

Comment: 6th blog post, with links to whole series: https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-5-hosting-repositories-bitbucket/

Answer (score 1):

I hope I'm not too late to this thread, but I couldn't get a proper solution anywhere & struggled for quite sometime. I am trying UI for the same, followed the exact steps from creating the SSH key to creating the secret key for the account 'builder', but end up with same error. following step may be helpful for people still looking for a solution

What worked for me is using repo url from "Clone with SSH" instead of "Clone with HTTPS"

[image: Screenshot]